# Is it unnatural to use "many" in this statement?

Tags: word-usage

I am used to use the word "many" in sentences, but today I came across the `grammar point` in [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lot_2?q=a+lot+of):

> Many is used only with countable nouns. **It is used mainly in questions
> and negative sentences.**

However, I see some examples in that page that "many" is used in a statement. So I wonder to see if it is natural to use "many" in the following sentence that I have written?

> For instance, having a sore throat is a common symptom for **many**
> diseases.

Comment: The page you linked states: "*...**especially** in negative sentences*", not "mainly". This means that while it's more common to find "many" in negative sentences and questions, it can also be used in statements. So yes, it's natural in that sentence you wrote.

Comment: "Especially" is a better description of the usage of "many" than "mainly". While both allow for it to be used in affirmative statements, "mainly" suggests it's unusual or unnatural, which is incorrect. The first link you had up described the situation better

Answer (score 1):

"diseases" is a "countable noun" and, therefore, is correct according to the Oxford Dictionary rule quoted above.  And, correct use is -- most likely -- a natural use of "many".

An uncountable noun example would be "advice".  You may get many comments (countable) for this question, but "many advice" is incorrect.